# Prompting user to switch on Bluetooth via Chrome

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating a new Bluetooth (BLE) product which users will interact with via their mobile phone.

I'd like to have an instructions webpage which tells users how to enable Bluetooth on their handset. It would be great if that page could detect whether Bluetooth is enabled on their handset and, if it isn't, prompt them to do so.

Is there any way I can use a webpage to detect whether or not Bluetooth is enabled on a handset? Initially on Android phones using Chrome and hopefully on iPhones using Chrome too.

Comment: Can't you do it from your BLE accessory app?

Comment: It won't work that way for this development unfortunately. Users who don't have Bluetooth enabled will be directed to a webpage with instructions. It would be very useful if that webpage could detect whether or not they have Bluetooth enabled already, and provide a relevant message.

Comment: You can't do this on iOS; you should do it in the app rather than the browser.

Comment: So it is possible in Android? Could you provide any links?